# Problem accessing RouterStateSnapshot on Angular function guards

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router-guards

Since the old method for Angular Guards (Class and injection token guards and resolvers) is deprecated (see [angular deprecation docs](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#router-class-and-injectiontoken-guards-and-resolvers)) , I'm trying to update the usages of guards in my project. But I'm facing problems getting `(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot)` in my guard function.

This is the **old method**:

*Routing Module*:

```js
{
    path: 'Home',
    canActivate: [MyGuard],
    component: HomeComponent 
}
```

*MyGuard*:

```js
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean 
  {
    // logic goes here
  }
}
```

in new method, I get error on calling `canActivate` : `Expected 2 arguments but git 0`

**New Method:**

*Routing Module*:

```js
{
    path: 'Home',
    canActivate: [() => inject(MyGuard).canActivate()],
    component: HomeComponent 
}
```

*MyGuard*:

```js
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Router, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyGuard {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean 
  {
    // logic goes here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the code snippet that describes the solution:

```js
{
    path: 'Home',
    canActivate: [(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => inject(MyGuard).canActivate(next, state)],
    component: HomeComponent
}
```